# Does the world simulate while underground?

Tags: forsaken-isle

When you are underground, does the overworld simulate with regards to crops growing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the crops growing while you are underground then yes! As long as you are in the same chunk as the crops or the crops are in the pawn chunks then they will grow!